# Basic Question on Conditional Expectation being in $L^2$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, measurable-functions

Suppose that $X,Y$ is a random-variables in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F};\mathbb{P})$, where $(\Omega,\mathcal{F};\mathbb{P})$ is a complete probability space.  Then the conditional expectation $E[X|\sigma(Y)]$ can be represented as a measurable function 
$$
g(Y)=E[X|\sigma(Y)],
$$
see [page 83](http://cyber.sibsutis.ru:82/Monarev/docs/nauka/PROBABILITY/Kallenberg%20O.%20Foundations%20of%20Modern%20Probability%20(Springer,1997)(ISBN%200387949577)(535s).pdf).

This may be a silly question, but can the map 
$$
y\mapsto E[X|\sigma(Y^{-1}[y])],
$$
be given meaning (or a modification of it), if so is it also in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F};\mathbb{P})$ (or at-least in $L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{F};\mathbb{P})$ for some $p \in [1,\infty)$).

Comment: I've never seen it written out that way, but Lemma 2.3.4 here may help:
https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387401010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix a measurable version of $g$ and define $E(X|Y=y)$ to be $g(y)$. Note that $g(Y) \in L^{2}$.

Comment: Is the function $g(y) \in L^p(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R});m)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $p \in [1,\infty)$?

Comment: It is in $L^{p}(\mathcal B(\mathbb R;\mu)$ where $\mu =P\circ Y^{-1}$.

Comment: Oh Right!  Perfect!  Thanks Kavi